# How to correctly use container class in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a navigation bar using bootstrap 4 to make responsive website.
But I believe it doesn't matter what version.
So, navigation bar is the topmost div in the viewport, right?

Do I have to use container class and put the navigation bar inside it?
Is it the right thing to do?
Then below it as the contents, do I have to create container class within container class?

Comment: Perhaps update your question with a sample of the HTML and CSS you have tried and the one challenge you have with that - best as a working snippet in your question.  As it stands this really just sounds like "help me search for a tutorial" or some such

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title question, one should carefully read the dedicated container documentation page: [v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#containers), [v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/containers/). It explains what container classes do and when they should be used.

To answer the more specific question:

> *Do I have to use container class and put the navigation bar inside it?*

- If the navigation bar is full page width (`100vw`), the `.container-fluid` wrapper is not necessary but is not wrong, either
- If the navigation bar is supposed to match the page content width (which is driven by a `container` or `container-{breakpoint}` class), you could either:

  - wrap the navbar in the same container class as the page content.
  - place the container wrapper around the navbar contents (making the container wrapper the only direct child of `.navbar`)

  Both solutions work and are correct.

---

**Notes** on correct usage of container classes:

- `.row`s should be directly wrapped in a container wrapper, as the container provides padding responsively, countering the negative margins of `.row`s, so you don't end up with those pesky horizontal scrollbars on the page
- `.container` (or `.container-{breakpoint}`) is meant to be used inside full page elements as a means to limit the contents to the container's width. You should avoid nesting containers (except for `.container-fluid` which can be used inside an element of any size).
- if ever in doubt, open up the [examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/) page, find one which matches your layout and study the DOM architecture. Those examples are written by the creators of Bootstrap. Each class is used as it's supposed to.

For your particular case have a look at [the navbar template example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/navbars/).